# Is it possible to use an existing Makefile to build a project in Code::Blocks?

Tags: c++, makefile, codeblocks

EDIT: I figured out that there is an option in Project properties to set a custom make file. Now the project build fine. Now, I am stumbled on how to specify the target executable to run when I click "Run".

Comment: So you want CodeBlocks to use a makefile that you have already built?

Comment: @Martin Yes, is there a way to do that?

Comment: @KeizerHarm If you want a walk-through you need to tell us what operating system it is to work on.

Comment: @MikeKinghan Windows 10. I guess I shoulda opened a new question, in hindsight.

Comment: Try to read this guide, hope it will help: [http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Code::Blocks_and_Makefiles](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Code::Blocks_and_Makefiles)

Answer (score 1):

[Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) is an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) (a buzzword for an editor capable of running other tools, including debuggers and compilers and probably some build automation tool), not a [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) (like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) is) or a [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool (like `make` or `ninja`, etc... are).

You don't have to use Code::Blocks to work on your C project. You could use any other [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) (I recommend [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), but the choice is ours) with other tools (compilers, linkers, build automation tool), that you can easily choose.

But if you do use Code::Blocks, be sure to read its [user manual](http://www.codeblocks.org/docs/main_codeblocks_en.html). Apparently, it is flexible enough to be configurable for your needs.

You can probably configure Code::Blocks to specify your project's executable. You probably want to configure it so that "build" means "run `make`". And since Code::Blocks is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), if that configuration is not possible, you could patch and improve Code::Blocks (work on Code::Blocks' source code!) to add that feature. And since Code::Blocks may have plugins, you might code your own plugin to add new features.

My recommendation, if you discover that you have to patch the source code of Code::Blocks to add some missing feature: switch to another editor; with `emacs` configuring what is running, etc... is a matter of a few lines in my `.emacs`; you can write your own `Makefile` after having read the [documentation of `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) and build your program by running `make` in a terminal; you probably can configure your IDE or source code editor to run that `make` command for you. Of course, you can run your [`gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) and your program in a terminal too....

Of course you have to configure your operating system correctly so that `make` works in a terminal. That could involve setting correctly your [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) (and perhaps even installing [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) on your system). How to do that is a different (and OS specific) question (unrelated to Code::Blocks).

Take the habit of reading the documentation of whatever software tools you are using.

Comment: At this instant, the Code::Blocks website is unaccessible to me. So I cannot find how to configure it. But you could (once the website works) and you certainly could patch it if that feature is missing

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is seems to not be very specific to Code::Blocks. I would appreciate a step-by-step sort of tutorial, or something of that nature. I just want to make my homework assignment which specifically requires the use of a Makefile to launch it.

Comment: So, you are not required to use Code::Blocks, but to provide a `Makefile`. Have you read the [documentation of `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html). Don't use Code::Blocks (or use it just as a source code editor). Compile in a terminal, by running `make`

Comment: Configuring my `emacs` to compile with `make` is *really* simple

Comment: @KeizerHarm: what operating system, what IDE or source code editor, what compiler, what debugger, are you using? Apparently you don't have to use Code::Blocks, so why do you use it if it is not suitable? Why don't you compile by typing `make` in a terminal (as apparently you are required to)?

Comment: @KeizerHarm: Bless your teacher for requiring a `Makefile` from you (and not caring about you using Code::Blocks or any other IDE)

Comment: Full story: this is my first time coding in C: I used Code::Blocks because that's what my roommate uses. I've not also tried NetBeans, which also seems a hell to configure. Operating system is Windows 10, so 'make' is not recognised as a command in the terminal.

Comment: I have an existing Makefile that I'm not supposed to touch, only use for running and testing ('make test').

Comment: So your OS is misconfigured (probably bad [PATH variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) settings). Correct your configuration to be able to run `make` in your terminal. So find out how to change your `PATH` and set it so that `make` works well.

Comment: The choice of Code::Blocks might be a poor one. And your reason for choosing it (my roommate is using it) is really a bad one. You should be responsible for choosing the right tools for the job. I recommend [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) (it is a matter of taste); you could use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/). But if you stick with Code::Blocks you should read its documentation! And if change for another editor, you still need to read the documentation of the tools you are using (including of `make` and of `g++`)

Comment: No reason to be so condescending about it.

Comment: Why are you assuming that I didn't?

Comment: If you really did read the documentation, you would have found how to solve your issue, and your question would have mentioned what you really tried (and the precise sections of the documentation that guided you)

Comment: I never asked the question. I only added a bounty to it because this person had the same problem as I.

Answer (score -4):

In [Project -> Properties... -> Build targets -> Output filename] you may specify the executable.

[Project -> Set programs' arguments...] allows to select a host application and command-line parameters.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I don't understand how it has 2 upvotes!