# How to start a CodeBlocks project from external code and Makefile?

Tags: c++, linux, unix, compiler-construction, codeblocks

I have C++ code that depends on boost and other libraries, and therefore this code has a makefile that invokes boost.

I am now trying to start developing this code in CodeBlocks in linux, so in order to do that I have two basic questions:

(1) How can I import the code into CodeBlocks as a CodeBlocks new project?  This seems to be a good rec: http://www.programmingforums.org/thread44976.html

(2) How do I invoke the makefile with CodeBlocks instead of CodeBlocks trying to compile the code (which would fail since CodeBlocks do not know that it needs to invoke boost)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most projects can be compiled without a makefile, so just include files, and if you need an extra library include that in a project. If your project uses header-only boost libraries and you have packet installed libboost-dev  (this is on my Debian) then it is included automatically. Else just use the proper library name in settings  (I can't remember if you need to append l to the name).

Answer (score 12):

**How can I import the code into codeblocks as a codeblocks new project?**

*File > New > Project > Empty project*

Create the project, then:

- right click on the project name on the "Projects" pane;
- add files recursively.

I recommend that you create Code::Blocks project new project at the top-level of your source (and not e.g. in a dedicated `~/codeblocks` directory), or else it will show long file paths.

**How do I invoke the makefile with codeblocks instead of codeblocks trying to compile the code (which would fail since codeblocks do not know that it needs to invoke boost)?**

Asked at: [Is it possible to use an existing Makefile to build a project in Code::Blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754196/makefile-project-in-codeblocks). For quick reference, the solution is to go to *Project > Properties* and toggle on the option *This is a custom Makefile*. Further options can be specified from the same window.

Comment: Disadvantage of adding the project at your codebase's top-level directory, is that purging the codebase local repo will erase the Project file. For example, with Mercurial, using "hg purge --all" will  erase the Project file.